# Handling duplicate identical rest requests. Java. Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, mq

There is such a set of modules
[image: schema]

1. Front sends a REST request to the API.
2. The API (RestController) generates a correlationId and sends a message to the queue via MQ. Depending on the request, it routes messages by specifying the operation code.
3. Process receives a message from the queue, and then performs some processing depending on the operation code.

The problem is that the Process can process data for about 5 minutes (other external services are slow). If the response does not come from the API to Front in 1 minute, it will resend the request to the API.

I need to make it so that when you receive exactly the same new request, the old request gave a response (no matter what, because the Front is not waiting for the answer), and the new sent message in the MQ queue, and waited for an answer instead of the first module Process.
The last active request should wait for an MQ response and return a normal response to Front, but only to the most recent one.

Are there any ready-made solutions or algorithms for this problem?

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Are you saying you want to cancel the pending request and resubmit or use its results to save time? Either way, you'll need to maintain a mapping of request to background task.

Answer (score 0):

If requests may be resent, you need to distinguish if an incoming request is a repetition or a new request, and then you can handle it appropriately.

To make this distinction, I would add a request counter to the session. In every successful response the client will get an increased request counter. If the client sends a request without having received a response it would send the request with the same request counter value as the previous request, thus the server can see there is something pending already.